# Создать во фрейме приближающийся/удаляющийся шар

Tags: graphics, java, swing

Каким образом можно стандартными методами нарисовать шар? Без использования OpenGL и т.д.
Может, формула какая есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таки вы правы, формула действительно есть.

[image]

Пробегите в цикле по значениям *θ*, а внутри него еще в одном цикле по значениям *φ*. И то и то от 0° до 360°, с нужным шагом. Получите координаты, останется линиями соединить. Это если вы хотите просто сетку нарисовать.

Если хотите красивый полигональный шар с освещением, придется попотеть побольше. Но тут как раз на хабре [выкладывают цикл статей про подобные штуки](http://habrahabr.ru/post/248153/).

Еще есть вариант с трассировкой лучей. Относительно несложно для одного шара. Поищите по ключевым словам "шар трассировка лучей".

Comment: Большое спасибо, мне только сетка нужна